# How can I extract some lines from a huge xml using prompt on windows?

Tags: xml, command-prompt, text-extraction

I have a huge xml and I want to extract from it only the first lines using prompt commands in a txt. 
Is it possible? How can I do? Thank you everyone.

Comment: What kind of command line?  bash?  cmd?  A port of the head command might be what you need.

Comment: It is cmd. Can you post an example to do what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses a helper batch file called findrepl.bat from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697

It will display from lines 1 to 5

```
type "file.xml" |findrepl /o:1:5
```